# Electricity from effervescence, is it possible?

Tags: electricity, power, renewable-energy

I've had this idea for quite some time (after having a cold and seeing Tabcin sparkling tablets), is there the possibility to generate electricity from effervescence? I envisioned something like the following:
[image]

Is it doable from a physics perspective? (Sorry if I sounded informal and un technical)

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a viable energy storage method called [Compressed-Air Energy Storage (CAES)](http://caes.pnnl.gov/) that works on a similar principle to what you suggest. During time when demand for electricity is low, electric compressors are used to compress air and store it deep underground. When demand for electricity peaks, the compressed air is then allowed to re-expand through turbines which generate electricity:

[image]

> <sup>Image source: [Edison Innovation Foundation](http://www.edisonmuckers.org/tag/compressed-air-energy-storage/)</sup>

Two of these plants currently exist, one in the [U.S.](http://www.powersouth.com/mcintosh_power_plant/compressed_air_energy) and one in [Germany](http://www.uni-saarland.de/fak7/fze/AKE_Archiv/AKE2003H/AKE2003H_Vortraege/AKE2003H03c_Crotogino_ea_HuntorfCAES_CompressedAirEnergyStorage.pdf). Effervescent tablets essentially **release pressurized gas** upon dissolution so it would generate power using the same mechanism as CAES. However, it is much more efficient to simply compress the gas rather than bother to make tablets, so I doubt it would gain much traction as an energy storage method.